# Trying to build react-native ios app bundle, error - Unable to execute JS call: __fbBatchedBridge is undefined

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to create an IOS app completely written in Javascript using react-native, i have tried running the app on simulator and its working fine, i have also tried running the app on my iphone 6s using my ip address in this line

```
jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://my_ip:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true"];
```

and this also works fine.

But when i try running the app after uncommenting the following line and commenting above

```
jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
```

I get this error [image]

I have images in my app and i have added them using JS directory structure not by xcode image assets of that helps.